# Removing ISO 9660 from USB using Terminal

Tags: terminal, osx, iso

I received a USB flash drive that contains a pre-installed ISO 9660 (Joliet) image on it. To delete the image and free up space on the drive, I attempted to use `sudo rm -rf /Volumes/ISONAME` via a Terminal; however, the command failed as the image is a `Read-only file system`. How should I go about deleting the ISO?

For reference, I'm running OSX 10.9.5.

Thanks so much!

Comment: OSX mounted the image as a CDROM.  You could use *Disk Utility* to format this (but that's for the Apple forum -- offtopic here).

Comment: Hi Thomas; Indeed, I first attempted to use _Disk Utility_ for this procedure. Unfortunately, _Disk Utility_ didn't recognize the ISO (i.e., the "CDROM" didn't appear within the application), hence why I considered using a Terminal instead.

Comment: I had in mind that you would reformat the flash drive itself (not rearrange the contents of the ISO).

Comment: Yep, I endeavored first to use the "Erase" option in _Disk Utility_ to clear then reformat flash drive. Erasing the drive did nothing to the ISO, though; and since the ISO / CDROM didn't even appear in _Disk Utility_, I was perplexed on my next steps.

Answer (score 1):

The large ISO file is just one file on the USB drive.  Your computer may simply have mounted the **ISO** as a filesystem (like a real CDROM).  In that case the `mount` command would show you this.

- [Mount & Unmount Drives from the Command Line in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/13/mount-unmount-drives-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x/)
- [How can I get the mount path of a USB device on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/429058/how-can-i-get-the-mount-path-of-a-usb-device-on-osx)

To really free up space, you might want to simply reformat the USB drive, making an empty filesystem.

The way to go with OSX is using Disk Utility, which can be used to format a variety of removable devices (as well as your computer's disks).

Here are a few useful links:

- [Format an External Hard Drive or USB Flash Drive for Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/04/format-an-external-hard-drive-or-usb-flash-drive-for-mac-os-x/)
- [How do I format a USB stick on my iMac](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4805253?start=0&tstart=0)
- [How to format a USB stick on a Mac using Disk Utility](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-format-usb-stick-on-mac-3434423/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly unmount the disk and note the device, eg. /dev/sdc1

Post that you have a number of options like,
- [dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223598/how-to-format-a-usb-stick) (CLI based, be very CAREFUL)
- [gparted](http://gparted.org) (GUI based)

Comment: Duly noted; I'll give these options a shot. Thanks!